# Control AVPlayer Buffer

Tags: ios, caching, avplayer, buffering, avplayeritem

I want to prevent a mp3 or audio stream from buffering past a certain amount of seconds. Apple's documentation for controlling buffer doesn't seem to be very helpful.

I tried using AVPlayerItem's preferredForwardBufferDuration and setting automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling to true, however it continues to buffer past the value that I've given it until the buffer is full or the song is completely buffered.

Can anyone help me??